# Make a link have the same width as the image above it

Tags: html, css

OK so today my brain is broken I can't figure this basic problem out. I want to have a LINK that goes underneath an image. The images may have different widths, let's say some are 100px wide and some are 200px wide:

```
<div>     
    <img src="image.jpg" style="auto;text-align:center;display:block;padding:1em;border: 5px solid #EFEFEF;">
    <a href="link.php" style="display: inline-block;background-color:blue">WORDS</a>
</div>
```

If I set the link's display to inline-block, it only takes up the space it needs to say "words". If I set it to block, the div stretched to accomodate it and it takes up 100% of the available space and is 5x too wide, much wider than the image.

I want the link to take up the whole width of the div, and I want the div to be as wide as the image (plus padding).

If I set the div's width in pixels, it doesn't look right if the image is a different width. What am I missing here?

Comment: What do you want to have the same width as the `div`?

Comment: the link, sorry I'll edit.

Comment: Why not put the image into the link? Undesired behavior?

Comment: The answer you accepted does not give you the result that matches your question.. If your putting 100% width on an image that is naturally 100px wide it is going to look like really bad and all this does is make the image the same width as the div and not the div the same width as the image like your question asked.. but to each his own. glad you got it worked out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the link style `display:block;` and maybe give your image a `width="100%"`

Comment: This does not give the result that the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 3):

The parent div will automatically be set to `display: block` which will span the entire length of the page. If you set the parent div to `display: inline-block` the div will only be as wide as the image. Then you set the link with a `width: 100%` and this should give you the results you are looking for.

here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/msechrest/k9s1vL44/) for you to see what i mean.

I have updated the fiddle to include 2 different size images. the key is you have to wrap each image and link in a new parent div.

Hope this helps!

*EDIT: If you would like to add a space between the image and the link with padding only give your image the top/bottom padding like so `padding: 1em 0;` and then add the side padding to the parent div like so `padding: 0 1em`.

Here is another [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/msechrest/k9s1vL44/3/) with that implimented.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? Let me know if I can improve this answer :)

```html
<div>
  <img src="image.jpg" style="auto;text-align:center;display:block;padding:1em;border: 5px solid #EFEFEF;">
  <a href="/link.php" style="display: block;background-color:blue; width:calc(100% - 10px); margin:auto;">WORDS</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose u ask something like this...

```html
<div style="width:100%; max-width:400px;">
    <img src="http://www.socialtalent.co/wp-content/uploads/blog-content/so-logo.png" style="auto;text-align:center;display:block; max-width:400px; width:100%; padding:1em;border: 5px solid #EFEFEF;">
    <a href="link.php" style="display: inline-block; background: blue; width: 100%; padding:0em 1em;border: 5px solid blue;">WORDS</a>
</div>
```

well as u see i've played with the width in all the elements to achieve it, and cheated on the "a" tags' border-padding. 
without setting a width on your image and your main div, you cant achieve what u asked unless u use javascript...

Comment: I beg to differ @Vinc have you taken a look at my answer?